# How to restore Ubuntu Server to default configurations without re-installing the whole system

Tags: server, restore, raspberrypi

I was asking if there was a way to restore ubuntu server 16.04 to its default configuration without having it re-installed again. It is installed on a Raspberry Pi

Comment: Back it up or make an image of it.

Answer (score 1):

**WARNINGS**

**Please use with caution and backup your system! Tested on Lubuntu and should work on Ubuntu.**

**When offered the option to delete GRUB, select *No* or this will render your OS unbootable!**

Requirements include:

- ISO image of your OS

Steps:

1. Mount your *ISO* so you can access these files:

   - `casper/filesystem.manifest`
   - `casper/filesystem.manifest-remove`
2. Combine the two files

   - Don't run this command in the *mounted iso folder*, create a folder to keep these files

     ```
     comm -3 <(cat filesystem.manifest | awk '{print $1}' | sort) <(cat filesystem.manifest-remove | sort) > default.txt
     ```
3. Get software currently installed on your system:

   ```
   dpkg --get-selections | awk '{print $1}' | sort > currently_installed.txt
   ```
4. Compare what we got from the `casper` files and what we got from step `3` we get added software(s):

   ```
   diff -u default.txt currently_installed.txt | grep "^+[^+]" | cut -c 2- > additions.txt
   ```
5. And to get what was removed:

   ```
   diff -u default.txt currently_installed.txt | grep "^-[^-]" | cut -c 2- > removed.txt
   ```
6. Now to remove all added software(s):

   ```
   sudo apt-get purge $(cat additions.txt)
   ```
7. And to add any removed software(s):

   ```
   sudo apt-get install $(cat removed.txt)
   ```
8. Remove configuration files:

   ```
   rm -rf .gnome .gnome2 .gconf .gconfd .metacity
   ```

**NOTE:**

1. You could always create an *image* of the system at *install* to reuse later (assuming your installing new), or
2. Re-install fresh, and
3. The files *paths* are assumed to be in the *folder* you created earlier, but if not then adjust your *paths* accordingly.
4. When offered the option to delete GRUB, **select *NO***.

[image]

Source for further information:

http://www.kingletas.com/2012/07/restore-ubuntu-to-the-default-settings-without-re-installing-it.html

Comment: Let me adjust it.

Comment: I see `dpkg-reconfigure` has an `all` option which will reset to default "all installed packages that use debconf". That might be easier to try first (after backing up anything important!) before trying the above answer. Hard to say without knowing why OP wants everything reset.